# Synchronizing clocks

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

In special theory of relativity, While deriving the Lorentz transformation equations we use spherical electromagnetic waves which start at $t=0$ when the origins of the two reference frames are coinsiding and the electromagnetic wave is emitting from the origin. Both inertial observer find the centre of the spherical electromagnetic wave to be at his own origin at all times even when the origin do not coincide how is this result related to to the prosedure of synchronizing clocks?

Answer (score 0):

In an inertial reference frame $S$ two clocks placed at $L$ and $-L$ from the origin (i.e. the origin is the middle of a rod and the clocks are located in each end) are synchronized when they start at the time they receive a signal at the origin.  Suppose you produce an identical rod with identical clocks, and the second bar then moves with constant speed in the $x$ direction, at a given moment the centers coincide. If at that time the light signal is sent then the clocks should start with synchronicity for both, rod one in $L$ and $-L$ and and for the other in $L'$ and $-L'$  although they would have different beats and $L \neq L'.$ But then you can use Lorentz transformations to go from $S$ to $S'.$